# Get the whole coordinates of line string in OpenLayers API - ReactJs

Tags: javascript, openlayers, react

I am working on a project where I am drawing a road with  OpenLayers map API as linestrings .
I could take the first and last coordinates of points of a the line.
This way:

```
drawend(e) {
    console.log('xxxxxxxxxxxxx, draw end', e);
    console.log("Co Ordinates :",e.feature.getGeometry().getCoordinates())
}
```

But I need to take data of all the line as an array.

Comment: Are you clicking two points on a vector feature, or do you need the road route between two points drawn over a raster background?  If the latter you would need to use a third party routing API.

Comment: Thank you very much ,i will check this API.